# Menu or button to change the value on a map Choroplethmapbox in Python and Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth, plotly-python

I would like to know if it is possible to change only the value of ‘z’ in a graph of the Choroplethmapbox type with a menu or button with python, something like:

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Choroplethmapbox(geojson=datosqgis, locations=df.id, z=df.Join_Count,
                                    colorscale="YlOrRd", zmin=0, zmax=80,
                                    marker_opacity=0.5, marker_line_width=0, layout =layout)
(...)
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        go.layout.Updatemenu(
            direction="down",
            active=0,
            x = 0.01,
            xanchor = 'left',
            y = 0.6,
            yanchor = 'bottom',
            buttons=list([
                dict(label="Año 2013",
                     method="restyle",
                     args=[{"z": df.Join_Count}]), #Value 2013
                dict(label="Año 2014",
                     method="restyle",
                     args=[{"z": df.Join_Count_2014}]), #Value 2014
                dict(label="Año 2015",
                     method="restyle",
                     args=[{"z": df.Join_Count_2015}]) #Value 2015
            ]),
        )
    ])
```

Although this code does not work for me, I tried loading several graphs with different value of ‘z’ and making them visible and invisible and if it works but I am loading the GEOJSON several times and that makes it heavier